# VueJS Navigation Bar links only clickable after zooming out in browser

Tags: html, css, vue.js

My navigation bar is as follows:

```
    <ul>
      <li @click="ClickedLink(1)" :class="{'li-active': currentActive == 1}">
        <div class="line-break"></div>
        <p>Goals</p>
      </li>
      <li @click="ClickedLink(2)" :class="{'li-active': currentActive == 2}">
        <div class="line-break"></div>
        <p>Praise</p>
      </li>
      <li @click="ClickedLink(3)" :class="{'li-active': currentActive == 3}">
        <div class="line-break"></div>
        <p>Ideas</p>
      </li>
      <li @click="ClickedLink(4)" :class="{'li-active': currentActive == 4}">
        <div class="line-break"></div>
        <p>Rewards</p>
      </li>
      <li @click="ClickedLink(5)" :class="{'li-active': currentActive == 5}">
        <div class="line-break"></div>
        <p>Profile</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

The issue is that the first two links do not work/aren't clickable but when I zoom out, and set the browser zoom level to 80%, then they work/are clickable.

Does anyone have any idea of what the issue could be?

Comment: did you try chrome dev tools and inspect that area, could be there are some element overlay the link making it unclickable. Also another suggestion is bind a method to that navigation link ( like console.log() something) and see after click , is there any msg in console. That way you can narrow down the click action is problem or the navigation logic  is problem

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I inspected and found that there was an element that was covering them. I suppose I'll have to shrink the element or give the navbar a greater Z-index.